# Checking to see if the Pascal Syntax is correct

Tags: pascal

Have a bit of a weird one and hopefully someone can help out.

The company I work for is doing an ad and we are looking for a Pascal programmer and we thought we'd incorporate some Pascal code into the ad itself. The only problem is we do not have any knowledge regarding Pascal. So after a little research the code we have come up with is:

```
Begin
 Write('Enter in Name:');
 readln(company);
 Write('Enter in Australia:');
 readln(country);
 writeln;{new line}
 writeln;{new line}
 Writeln('Programming specialists:', 'company' ,'country');
 Readln;
End.
```

And what we are trying to say is:

The person types in **Name**
And then types in **Australia**
And then on the screen appears **Programming specialists: Name Australia**

So is the syntax correct are we missing anything? like comma's or semi-colons etc

Comment: The last time I programmed in Pascal was in 2003 (1st semester of Computer Engineering course). I can barely remember a thing. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems fine to me. I'm pretty fresh for programming in Pascal - did it in my college course only a couple of months ago. Take into account casablanca's comment though.

Also, make sure you have the top half of the program correct. Like so:

```
Program advert; {or any other pertinent name}
Uses crt; {This may be unneeded, but we were taught to always put it in}

Var
company, country: string;

Begin
    Writeln('Enter in name');
     {Writeln or write depends on how you want this to work - write will make the input on the same line (in a terminal) and writeln will make the input on line below}
    Readln(company);
    Write('Enter in Australia');
    Readln(country);
    Writeln;
    Writeln;
    Writeln('Programming specialists: ', company, ' ', country);
    Readln;
End.
```

In regards to the `Readln` at the end of the program, you might not need to use it. This essentially 'pauses' the program until the user presses the `enter` key. I noticed that in Windows the command prompt had a habit of closing at the end, making a final `readln` necessary, but in a Linux terminal, running the program from the terminal, this doesn't happen. *Just a side note for you to consider.*

Answer (score 2):

It seems fine except for this line:

```
Writeln('Programming specialists:', 'company' ,'country');
```

You're printing the strings "company" and "country", but I assume you actually want the values entered by the user. So it should be:

```
Writeln('Programming specialists:', company ,country);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could test this yourself with [Free Pascal](http://www.freepascal.org/).

Answer (score 0):

you must remove the `'` (single cuotes) character from the company and country variables, try this

```
var
company,country :string;
Begin
 Write('Enter in Name:');
 readln(company);
 Write('Enter in Australia:');
 readln(country);
 writeln;{new line}
 writeln;{new line}
 Writeln('Programming specialists:', company,' ' ,country);
 Readln;
End.
```

you can check [this](http://www.marcocantu.com/epascal/English/default.htm) free ebook to learn more  about the pascal syntax

[Marco Cantù's Essential Pascal](http://www.marcocantu.com/epascal/EssentialPascal.zip)